# What is wrong with my proof by contradiction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> There exist no integers $a$ and $b$ for which $18a+6b=1$.

*Proof*: Assume that $18a+6b=1$. We find that
$$6(3a + b)=1$$
which leads to
$$3a+b=\frac16$$
We know that the sum of two integers can't produce a non-integer result, therefore a contradiction arises, as the proof demonstrates that two integers can produce a non-integer value. $\blacksquare$

My professor said that if one ends up with fractions in a proof, there is likely a problem. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: I really don’t know what he had in mind; I suspect that he was talking about some rather particular context, but it’s not clear what it might have been. Your argument here is fine.

Comment: Maybe your prof wanted a proof using integers, only. In that case you can stop at `6(3a + b)=1` and say that it proves $6|1$ which is false.

Comment: @dxiv That's a great answer; why don't you post it?

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, but that's essentially the same as the answer already posted by KonKan. Plus, I'd have to explain why $6|1$ is false ;-)

Comment: Perhaps your professor was implying that using fractions might implicitly require theorems that either rely on what you're proving (i.e. are circular) or are just generally beyond was is necessary for such a problem or what they desire to be used. (You could always ask the professor what they meant though)

Comment: My two cents.  I'm assuming he doesn't like foo = 1/6 when we don't have the concept of the rationals yet.  But if so he should have just said *that*.

Answer (score 28):

I'm assuming you're in a number theory class or abstract algebra. At this level of such a course, we haven't formally reintroduced $\Bbb Q $ so fractions don't formally exist yet.

We have multiplication and addition. And we have the integers.

The better proof is to show that $\gcd(18,6)=6$ and hence that the smallest positive linear combination of $18$ and $6$ we can make is $6$.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is how my professor later explained it, using greatest common denominators.

Comment: Greatest common divisors* you mean

Comment: Sorry, but that's just wrong. There is no such thing as "the correct proof". His proof is fine, except for using $\frac{1}{6}$. You don't need to introduce $\Bbb Q$ to be able to say that $6$ does not divide $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Here I made it say "better"

Comment: The better proof is actually to say that he received a message from Jesus that there are no integers $a,b$ in a dream. This is called induction on Jesus.

Answer (score 23):

The core idea of your argument looks fine to me. 
I suspect what your professor had in mind, is that you should not write $3a + b = \frac{1}{6}$. You should simply say that 
$$
6(3a + b)=1
$$
is not possible in integers, since $6$ is not an invertible element in $\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 23):

$18a+6b=2\cdot(9a+3b)$ is an even number, so it cannot equal $1$ which is an odd number.

Comment: This is a nice easy proof...but it doesn't answer the the OP's question of whether his was valid.

Comment: @Beska I had a comment about that under the main post, which I didn't repeat here.

Comment: I can't see  why it should make more  sense  to  claim that 2 does  not divide 1 than  that 6 does not divide 1.

Comment: @miracle173 I didn't claim it did. But depending on the (untold) context, the notion that *every* integer is either even *or* odd (never both) may have been introduced earlier than the more general statement that 1 has no non-trivial divisors such as 6.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @reinierpost If you mean this part of the question `My professor said that if one ends up with fractions in a proof, there is likely a problem. Can someone explain why this is the case?` then, yes, I did address it both directly in a comment under the main question, and indirectly in the answer above. Beyond that, there isn't really any possible definitive answer since the OP provided too little context to know (or even guess) the particular reason his professor rejected fractions in such answers.

Answer (score 12):

Well, all the reasoning is sound here, but, actually, one might ask why exactly $\frac 1 6$ is not integer? To properly answer this, one needs to know how rational numbers are defined. Well, let us assume that $\frac 1 6$ is integer. That means that there is integer $k$ such that $\frac 1 6 = \frac k 1$. From the definition of rationals, this happens if and only if $6k = 1$ (as you can see, we are back to your original question). To finish argumentation, one argues that $6$ does not divide $1$ in $\Bbb Z$ to get contradition, so $\frac 1 6$ can't be integer.

Comment: Isn't `6 does not divide 1 in Z` literally equivalent to `1/6 is not in Z`?

Comment: Of course it is, but "$1/6$ is not integer" is statement about rational numbers, while "$6$ does not divide $1$ in $\Bbb Z$" is statement about integers. Since rationals are constructed from integers, I believe that "$6$ does not divide $1$" is more fundamental than the other one. @dxiv

Comment: @dxiv, what I want to say is that if you can give me proof that $1/6$ is not integer without using divisibility in $\Bbb Z$, then the OP's proof is good. For example, characterize $\Bbb Q$ as countable, dense, linear order without endpoints. I can't see how this would work.

Comment: Maybe $a|b \implies |a| \le |b|$ depending on the context. But the OP gave so little context that it's hard to guess what *is* acceptable to use within the proof.

Comment: @dxiv, I agree, this is just a speculation what the professor might find "morally wrong" with the proof using rationals.

Comment: 1/6 is not an integer because six of these buggers fit into the interval [0,1]. :)

Comment: @Kaz, well yeah, but what does it even mean if you don't repeat the whole construction $\Bbb N\to \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Q$? Assuming you have $\Bbb Q$ by other means and not as field of fractions of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Well here I think your professor means that if you add two integers, you should never get a number that is not an integer.

This is because the integers are "closed" under addition (and also multiplication). Mathematically speaking, any two elements of the integers say $a$ and $b$ can be combined as $a+b$ or $ab$ and still only give a result that is an integer.

Side note: why might the integers not be closed under division?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fact that sum , difference of even numbers produces even numbers only. $18a, 6b$ are even. I can't say exactly what he meant but I guess  he meant using only properties explained till that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.
However, it's a bit too complicated.

You could just show the left-hand side is even for all integer $a$ and $b$, while RHS is always odd, so they are never equal.